# Divide an isosceles triangle with an non equal angle of $45$ degrees triangle into $3$ parts

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

the three parts can be turned, and are called $a, b \text{ and }c$, and part $a$ can form an isosceles triangle with part $b$, part $c$ with $b$, and $a$ with $c$, without leaving any hole or superposition

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Too hard to parse what you mean.  Please either include a picture or be more explicit with you description.  It seems you are asking about a triangle with a vertex of $45$ degrees (and therefore the base angles will each be $67.5$ degrees) but what does "turning" mean and what does "$a$ can form an isoceles trianglel with $b$" mean?

Answer (score 1):

i already solved it so i will answer myself

[image]

the drawing is not exact because i made it with paint, but it makes sense on paper, notice that the triangle A with B is isosceles, B with C is also isosceles and B is equal to C so A can form an isosceles triangle with C if C is rotated